# Loading DICOM image Qt C++

Tags: c++, qt, dicom

How do I load a simple dicom image using QT c++ GUI application?

I tried to follow this link
http://hxr99.blogspot.com/2013/03/qt-vtk-displaying-single-dicom-file.html

As per that, I downloaded vtk and Cmake. But I could not see the Cmake executable file to run it.

I don't see any helpful links in the internet. Some of the links ask to download the dicom library. Can anyone guide me regarding this?

Comment: You are not very specific. Did you compile VTK? what version are you using? what is your problem exactly? What OS are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You could have a look at [MITK](http://mitk.org) which integrates VTK, Qt and the two DICOM toolkits GDCM and DCMTK. The [build instructions](http://docs.mitk.org/nightly/StartingDevelopment.html) should help you getting started.